# Statistics: Finding Probability Without Using De Morgan's

Tags: statistics

[image]

How to do question **d)** without using De Morgan's?

**My try:**

Since $P(A_1A_2) \ne P(A_1)P(A_2)$ and $P(A_2A_3) \ne P(A_2)P(A_3)$ and $P(A_1A_3) \ne P(A_1)P(A_3)$ according to the question, the events are dependent.

Thus,

$P(A^{'}_1A^{'}_2A^{'}_3) = P((A^{'}_1A^{'}_2)A^{'}_3)$

$= P(A^{'}_1A^{'}_2|A^{'}_3)P(A^{'}_3)$

$= \frac{P(A^{'}_1A^{'}_2)}{P(A^{'}_3)}P(A^{'}_3)$

$= \frac{0.64}{P(A^{'}_3)}P(A^{'}_3)$ using answer from b)

$= 0.64$

**Actual answer:**

```
0.47
```

Comment: I've tutored probability for years. Why would you **want** to do d) without DeMorgan's?

Comment: in step 3), is $\frac{P(A_1'A_2'A_3')}{P(A_3')}$, ie returns to original expression

Comment: I think you would just have to derive deMorgan's for 3 sets as part of your answer and then use it.

Comment: $P(A'\cap B' \cap C')=1-P(A)-P(B)-P(C)+P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap C)+P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap B\cap C)$. Do you need further proof of this fact?

Comment: So what was wrong with my equation to get an answer of 0.64? It seemed logical enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could do "proof by Venn diagram" (which, by the way, is not a proof):

[image]

The event $A_1^{\prime} \cap A_2^{\prime} \cap A_3^{\prime}$  is everything outside of these circles.

The sum of everything inside these circles is $$0.07+0.10+0.08+0.04+0.01+0.06+0.17 = 0.53$$
thus we have $1-0.53 = 0.47$.

Comment: Didn't check all the arithmetic, but this is certainly a reasonable approach. And a nice diagram. (+1)